# How to load data infile mysql workbench for AWS RDS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, cmd, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I am trying to import a CSV file into my AWS RDS database through mysql workbench by using Load Data Infile. I was able to load the data infile for a local db I created. For that local database I used the following format in cmd:

```
CREATE DATABASE db;

USE db;

CREATE TABLE data(id, name, description);

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 
"C:/Users/bbrown/Projects/Database/NSF/nsf_04_17_2019.csv" INTO TABLE data
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(id, name, description);
```

This creates the database with the table containing all the data from the csv.
For the AWS RDS database it created a database called innodb, how can I import the same CSV file into that database? (I do not want to use the "Table Data Import Wizard" because it takes too long to import the CSV file).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is by logging into mysql in cmd like this:

```
mysql -h (aws endpoint) -P 3306 -u username -p
```

Then it will prompt you for your password(keep in mind, the username and passwords are the ones you created on AWS). I hope this helps anyone else who also struggled with this

Comment: How's its work where is db file which user want to import in DB?

Answer (score 0):

use following command

`mysql -u {username} -p {database} < {your_db_sql_file or .sql.zip file}`